# No 'binary' type with Doctrine 2.4.4

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to use the `binary` type of Doctrine 2.4.4 using Symfony 2.5.1 as shown in the Doctrine documentation:

http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/types.html#binary

With this code:

```
<?php
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="admins")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SG\AdminBundle\Entity\AdminRepository")
 */
class Admin
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="binary", length=64, options={"fixed" = true})
     */
    private $password;
}
```

And I get this error while executing the command `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
>   Unknown column type "binary" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with `\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType()`. You can get a list of all the known types with `\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap()`. If this error occurs during database introspection then you might have forgot to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use `AbstractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping()` or have your custom types implement `Type#getMappedDatabaseTypes()`. If the type name is empty you might have a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping information.

When I check the Doctrine sources at `./vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/`, there is no such `binary` type.

Answer (score 3):

In fact `binary` type is available since v2.5.0 only: ["introduce BinaryType" commit on github](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/commit/d3f94a52e0bd10c9a2b115eee6c54b15b0ededd4#diff-609261c9f33e47f92a885bf738dce989)

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [doctrine website](http://www.doctrine-project.org/2014/01/01/dbal-242-252beta1.html), you need Doctrine DBAL v2.4.2 (at least) in order to use the binary type.

What is your Doctrine DBAL version?